# serve webp images. picture element vs htaccess

Tags: image, .htaccess, webp

HTML5 webpage, .webp images with .jpg fallback. Use the HTML  element method or use mod-rewrite rules in .htaccess method. Are there any gotchas or performance issues related to each method ?

**1:** HTML  element example.
`

```
<picture>
  <source type="image/webp"  srcset="img_pink_flowers.webp">
  <source srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

**2:** Mod-rewrite rules in .htaccess file example.
`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Check if browser supports WebP images
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp

  # Check if WebP replacement image exists
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f

  # Serve WebP image instead
  RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=REQUEST_image]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Vary: Accept for all the requests to jpeg, png and gif
  Header append Vary Accept env=REQUEST_image
</IfModule>
```

`
Thanks
Milo

I have tried both with a simple html doc containing 1 image and the performance looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `.htaccess` method your HTML markup will be lighter. If you have a shop for example with many products or a photo gallery it will be a slight difference because less data will be transmitted to the client. In rest is the same.